# Geany1.32 using Miktex2.9 can not compile biblatex

Tags: latex, pdflatex, geany, miktex, biblatex

I am trying to migrate to Geany as my main IDE for LaTeX documentation. I am using windows 10 and MiKTeX2.9 (64bit). 
I am editing an article document which calls a number of .bib files containing my bibliography information. Reading the comments and recommendations on many different pages, I came up with this commands in my preamble :

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=numeric{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibliography/refs_book.bib}

Also in Build -> Set Build Commands dialogue I set LaTeX commands as bellow :
[image: Set Build Commands]

And I follow the rule of compiling the .tex file one time with pdflatex then compiling the .aux file one time with biber and then re compiling the .tex file twice with pdflatex command. However in compiling the .aux file I get an error as bellow:

[image: Compilation Error]

It is interesting to notice that at the end I will get some sort of citation in the generated .pdf, however they are not in the format that I want (numeric) them to be, besides the references are not visible at the end of the article.

This is an example of the citation from the text :

[image: Wrong Citation Style]

Considering that I updated the packages using "MikTeX package manager" (in both user and admin modes), I wonder if the way I introduced the LaTeX Commands should be the cause of Error ?

Any help in this is much appreciated.
Best Regards, 
Sina

Comment: Well… Based on the error I don't think it's something you can fix inside Geany. Check your MikTeX-installation

Comment: Thanks frlan, you are right. I removed the basic MiKTeX installation package and installed the big (~2.6 GB) package of proTeXt (without text studio). Everything is fine now and I have my citations in the numeric style.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by installing a more complete and robust MiKTex package which is included in the [proTeXt](http://www.tug.org/protext/)  bundle. Now following the instructions [here](http://mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html#batch) using the command (latexmk -pdf -pv "%f") for compiling/building and generating .pdf works fine and the citations are in the style that I want.